# how to install mysql/phpmyadmin into pendrive

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, usb-drive

i have a requirement.how can i do it.i have to keep my php files in wamp server but phpMyadmin in penDrive.is is possible.if possible how can i do this.how about database configurations.

thank u.

Answer (score 1):

You could try **[uWamp](http://www.uwamp.com/en/)** . Its a  Zip archive, just unpack it and you can run the wamp server.

An alternative is **[XAMPP Lite](http://download.cnet.com/XAMPP-Lite/3000-10248_4-75157363.html)**. 
[Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14998/turn-your-flash-drive-into-a-portable-web-server/) is tutorial on how to use it.

Comment: u mean we have to install it on pendrive right

Comment: For uWamp, you could just unzip and use. No need to install.

Comment: ok how to access files and phpmyadmin from uWamp.plz.

Comment: [Use this](http://www.uwamp.com/en/?page=doc)

Comment: @SudheerBabuT Please mark the answer as correct or upvote if it was useful.